# Exiting Fullscreen in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component which contains an element that I put in fullscreen using the html5 FullScreen API (RequestFullScreen).

For example,

```js
handleFullScreenClick() {
    if (this.refs.myElement.requestFullscreen) {
      this.refs.myElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.refs.myElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      this.refs.myElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (this.refs.myElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      this.refs.myElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }
```

Now, I wish to be able to exit the fullscreen when a button is pressed for example. When I searched the fullscreen API, I saw that the ExitFullScreen function must be called by the document element, which is not accessible to a react component.

Is there any way I can access the document element in my react component in order to call the ExitFullScreen function?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: some code please?

Comment: Added the way I put my element into fullscreen

Comment: `document` is globally accessible so you can just use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the document element, which is not accessible to a react component

Don't know who told you this but it's not true (also `document` is not an element). [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface is represented by a global object `document` which is available in any part of your JS code. So you just can use it directly:

```
handleExitFullScreenClick() {
  document.webkitExitFullscreen()
}
```